# Build-in resizing tools for controls?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a small program where the user could resize the controls by dragging the border.

Much like many editing software, such as Office, Paint 3D, or even VS itself, would do.

I learned how to do it from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845986/resizable-textbox-in-winforms).

But how can I make it more "professional looking"?

Because in all the editing software, "little square dragging handles" will appear once you select the control, just like the following picture.

[image]

I had thought about maybe change the background image upon mouse enter, but then I thought, "since VS have all that functionality when you making a form, there must be a way to employ it directly, right"!?

But unfortunately I can not find any documents online related to it! Probably because this is "not" something most of the people would do and requires more professional knowledges.

So, could somebody please be so kind and help me out!?

Probably through some `using` or importing some dll or something, much appreciated!

Comment: This is not trivial to do, and there are a lot of steps to achieve this in a bullet proof way in the way you described. Your best bet is to find and try every library or backwater code you can to do this. Otherwise you are in for a long learning curve.

Comment: @TheGeneral Could you please be so kind and teach me how to do it? "Learning" is not a problem for me. Unless it's "WAY~" beyond my ability and requires some kind of PhD-level knowledge, I think I can find a way to understand it. ^O^

Comment: [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40209045/14171304)